# Concatenating Dataset columns in Apache Spark using Java by passing an array with column names as array elements?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is what I want to achieve using Java and Spark.

I have an array of column names as below.

```
String[] col_arr = new String[] { "colname_1", "colname_2"};
```

I want to concat the 2 columns by passing the array (with column names as array elememts) in the concat function.

```
Dataset<Row> new_abc = dataset_abc.withColumn("new_concat_Column", concat(col_arr));
```

The below code is working but I do not want to pass the column names explicitly, instead I want to pass the array contaning the column names as array elements.

```
Dataset<Row> new_abc = dataset_abc.withColumn("new_concat_Column", concat(col("colname_1"), col("colname_2")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an array of columns, `Column[]` to the concat function like so:

```
Column[] columnArray = {
    col("column1"), col("column2") 
    };
Dataset<Row> concatenatedDS = dataset.withColumn("concatenated_column", concat(columnArray));
```

If you only have a `String[]` array, you can build a `Column[]` array with it dynamically.